# "How to Ask" box is out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, mso-mse-split

So due to the split between MSO and MSE, the "How to Ask" box when you ask a question on meta.so sill has "Is your question about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange engine that powers the Stack Exchange network?", should the Stack Exchange engine part of the sentence be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should, and it has.

With you <strike>in the next build</strike> now.